# override life cycle method in ivy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to override some life cycle methods of Angular Components when I have just an instance of the component so extending is not a deal.

I want to achieve something like that
https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy/blob/master/src/take-until-destroy.ts
to run some code before or after the lifecycle is called.

The way from the library works on the ViewEngine but doesn't with Ivy.

During my researches I noticed that the ViewEngine runs method from the class so I have a place to override that before the function is called but Ivy collect all lifecycles at the begining in core.js so my changes will not have affect because they don't change function stored in view.destroyHooks array.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that goal?

core.js

```
/** Calls onDestroy hooks for this view */
function executeOnDestroys(view) {
    var tView = view[TVIEW];
    var destroyHooks;
    if (tView != null && (destroyHooks = tView.destroyHooks) != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < destroyHooks.length; i += 2) {
            var context = view[destroyHooks[i]];
            // Only call the destroy hook if the context has been requested.
            if (!(context instanceof NodeInjectorFactory)) {
                destroyHooks[i + 1].call(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to disable `ivy` in `AngularCompiler`?

Comment: But Ivy is the future and I'm thinking about putting it in the library, so I don't want to create something that will soon stop working.

Comment: To disable use `"angularCompilerOptions": {... "enableIvy": false,...}` in your `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: I know how to do that but I won't. As I wrote above...